# Bash Cat file to terminal centre

Tags: bash, cat, ascii

I have a text file with aome ascii art in it. I am trying to get it to print to the terminal on terminal start. I know to do this i add cat myfi in my .bashrc. i am stuck trying to get the output of cat to centre. I have tried using tput cols unsuccessfully.

Can anyone give me some tips or if this is possible.

Comment: By "centre", do you mean you want to position the image so that its longest line is centered?

Comment: After adding any thing in .bashrc you need to execute the command using source .bashrc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is with the following steps:

- get width of terminal
- find the longest line in the ASCII art file
- take the difference between those numbers and divide by 2 to get the needed indentation
- print the ASCII art file, with each line indented

Here's a sample script, which uses `awk` to do the calculations:

```
#!/bin/sh
input="$1"
twidth=$(tput cols)
echo terminal width is $twidth
indent=$(awk -v twidth=$twidth '    {
                                     w=length();
                                     if (w > fwidth) fwidth=w;
                                    }
                                END {
                                     indent=int((twidth-fwidth)/2);
                                     print (indent > 0 ? indent : 0);
                                    }' < "$input")
echo indent is $indent
awk -v indent=$indent '{ printf("%*s", indent, " "); print; }' < "$input"
```

And here's a test on a large letter L:

```
$ cat /tmp/L
#
#
#
#
#
#
#######

$ ./center /tmp/L
terminal width is 81
indent is 37
                                     #
                                     #
                                     #
                                     #
                                     #
                                     #
                                     #######
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This script did the trick. I just disabled the echos of the terminal width and indent. Setup the bashrc to run the command and pass the ascii file to the script works flawlessly.

Answer (score 3):

```
sed -e 's/^/                   /' /path/to/ascii_art
```

Adjust the spaces, if it's not enough.

Answer (score 0):

`example.txt`:

```
praveen
ajay
```

Now I am adding 15 space in beginning using awk to get content in center.
You need to increase the space number as per requirement

```
awk '{printf "%15s\n",$1}' example.txt
```

Comment: I've edited your answer to make it more readable (it had been automatically flagged by the system software for possible deletion). I guessed that the first 3 lines were intended to indicate a filename along with its contents. I'd suggest that you [edit] it further to improve its quality. See [answer].

Answer (score 0):

A more programmatic way of doing things (center both horizontally and vertically) :

The following can be put in a "cat_center.sh" file :

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# Get file in variable
LOGO=$(cat "$1")

# Work out logo size
H_SIZE=0
V_SIZE=0
while IFS= read -r line; do
    if [[ ${#line} -ge H_SIZE ]]; then
        H_SIZE=${#line}
    fi
    V_SIZE=$((V_SIZE + 1))
done <<<"$LOGO"
#echo "Horizontal size : $H_SIZE"
#echo "Vertical size : $V_SIZE"

# Work out the horizontal offset
H_WIDTH=$(tput cols)
H_OFFSET=0
if ((H_WIDTH > H_SIZE)); then
    H_OFFSET=$(((H_WIDTH - H_SIZE) / 2))
fi
#echo "Horizontal offset : $H_OFFSET"

# Work out the vertical offset
V_WIDTH=$(tput lines)
V_OFFSET=0
if ((V_WIDTH > V_SIZE)); then
    V_OFFSET=$(((V_WIDTH - V_SIZE) / 2))
fi
#echo "Vertical offset : $V_OFFSET"

# Print the ascii art
clear
# Vertical offset : print spaces and convert to lines
printf '%*s' $V_OFFSET | tr ' ' '\n'
# Horizontal offset : print offset of spaces
while IFS= read -r line; do
    printf "%"$H_OFFSET"s${line}\n"
done <<<"$LOGO"
```

Usage : ./cat_center.sh my_logo_file